# Expected value of almost surely equal random variables

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, independence, almost-everywhere

Let $X, \ Y, \ Z \in L^1$ be random variables such as $X = Y $ a.s.
Is it in general true that $EXZ=EYZ$?

It is surely true if Z is independent of X and Y, cause $EXZ=EXEZ=EYEZ=EYZ. $

But is it true in general? I tried counting $EZX-ZY=EZ(X-Y)$ I think that $X-Y=0$ a.s. hence the integral (expectation) is zero and $EZX=EZY $. Is it correct?

And another question if Z is independent of X, does it imply that Z is independent of Y? How can I prove it, or what is the counterexample?

Comment: Re your first query, note that $T=Z(X-Y)$ is such that $P(T=0)=1$ and that every such random variable $T$ is integrable and such that $E(T)=0$ because its distribution is the Dirac mass at $0$. The second question can be answered similarly.